# Trouble with formatting values in QSQLTableModel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Subclassing QSQLTableModel and overriding the data method:

```
class SclDataModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SclDataModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def data(self, index, role=None):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if index.column() == 2 or index.column() == 3:
                val = QSqlTableModel.data(self, index, Qt.DisplayRole) #<--Is set to None on cell edit.
                print('Value={}'.format(val))   
                return '${:,.2f}'.format(val)
            else:
                return super(SclDataModel,self).data(index,role)
        elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return Qt.AlignVCenter | Qt.AlignRight
        else:
            return QVariant()
```

The values render correctly when the table is loaded; however, when I edit one of items I get an error formatting the value which comes through as a NoneType.  Oddly, when I insert a new row and edit the value, it formats properly.

[image]

If I edit this value I get the following error:

```
Value=None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/DevServer/Python/PPSBooks/SvcData/scldata_browse.py", line 39, in data
    return '${:,.2f}'.format(val)
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__
```

Comment: I am attempting to format the values (for display) as  US Money

Comment: You could show a picture of what you point out

Comment: Do you want the "$" symbol to appear when you edit?

Comment: No, just when it is displayed in the table.

Comment: okay, one last question: what type of field are the columns in database that you want to be modified?

Comment: Using MySql and the fields are DECIMAL(10,4)

Comment: As I point out in my solution, the task is not of the model but of the delegate :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it is not advisable to modify the model since it represents the data, and in your case the symbol $ is only visual, so the visual task is of the delegate:

```
class MoneyDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(MoneyDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.text = '${:,.2f}'.format(index.data())
        option.displayAlignment = Qt.AlignVCenter | Qt.AlignRight

...

view = QTableView()
delegate = MoneyDelegate(view)
for i in (2, 3):
    view.setItemDelegateForColumn(i, delegate)
```

On the other hand, if you are going to modify data, the default role is `Qt::DisplayRole`:

```
class SclDataModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        ...
```

**Update:** If you want to modify the editor, you must overwrite the `createEditor()` method of the delegate:

```
class MoneyDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(MoneyDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.text = '${:,.2f}'.format(index.data())
        option.displayAlignment = Qt.AlignVCenter | Qt.AlignRight

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = super(MoneyDelegate, self).createEditor(parent, option, index)
        if any(isinstance(editor, t) for t in (QDoubleSpinBox, QSpinBox)):
            editor.setMinimum(0)
            editor.setMaximum(2**15)
        return editor
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  Thanks.  Would I use the same delegate to setup the spinboxes for editing??

Comment: @Elcid_91 the delegates have 2 parts: what is used for the mode without editing that is the one we have used now and the other for the edition that you can use for the editor, depending on what you want you could indicate the appropriate method. What do you want to modify of the QDoubleSpinbox?

Comment: I want to set minimums and maximums.

Comment: Thanks again for putting up with all my questions. Still learning the Qt5 model and you have a an extremely valuable resource.